# Find a value (and its left cell value) in another spreadsheet similar to my current value

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a problem regarding Google spreadsheets. I'm not very experienced in google spreadsheets but I know some basics.

My problem is:
I have google spreadsheet document with two sheets called `categories` and `usages`.

Categories:

[image: Sheet categories]]

Usages:

[image: Sheet usages]]

In the categories sheet I have two columns with `main category` and `sub category`. There are many sub categories which belong to the same main categories and therefore I have ~ 15 sub categories and ~ 3 main categories.

In the other sheet I want to write down usages of each sub category. Next to the selected sub category should be the main category automatically.
I can select the sub category via data-validation. The only thing (ha!) I want to have is to find out which main category belongs to the selected sub category.

I imagine something like "look for `sub category x` in `categories` sheet and find the value right next of it and write it here".

How can I find a value (and its left cell value) in another spreadsheet similar to my current value?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer by myself.
The magic function is `LOOKUP`.

In this case I added a this (in row 2):

```
=LOOKUP($B2; categories!$B$1:$B$20; categories!$A$1:$A$20)
```

I've also added an IF statement, if the subcategory is empty:

```
=IF(COUNTA($B2);LOOKUP($B2; categories!$B$1:$B$20; categories!$A$1:$A$20);)
```